# Which python to install if I have an Intel Core i7 and 64-Bit Windows 7?

Tags: python, 64-bit

I have to install Python 2.5.4 from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/ which is required for [the pcraster program](http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/downloads/).

However there are three python choices
For x86 processors: python-2.5.4.msi
For Win64-Itanium users: python-2.5.4.ia64.msi
For Win64-AMD64 users: python-2.5.4.amd64.msi

I know I have Win64 but I am not sure if my i7 processor is Itanium or AMD?
Can someone knowledgeable please help me?

Comment: You're most likely using a desktop so the non-Itanium one is probably the one you'd be interested in.  Itanium processors are typically in servers or other HPC systems.

Comment: @Jeff: my experience is that Itanium processors are typically not seen at all ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records:

As of now (2023-March-09) the latest Python version with installer which runs on Windows 7 is release 3.8.10

Source: [Python 3.8.10 Windows Installer (64-bit)](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/python-3.8.10-amd64.exe) from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/

Answer (score 20):

Install the Win64-AMD64 version. Since AMD won the race to implement the 64 bit architecture before Intel, the architecture is still commonly known as AMD64.

### Irony!

Intel licensed x86 architecture to AMD. Years later. AMD licensed AMD64 (based on the x86 architecture) to Intel!

Read more about it from Wikipedia: [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Industry_naming_conventions).

Comment: Not really. Intel went with a non-backwards compatible architecture called IA64, but AMD choosed to go for a backwards compatible one, the x86-64. AMD's choice won for obvious reasons-

Answer (score 13):

Both the 32- and 64-bit (AMD) versions will work on a 64-bit Win7 system.  Which you want to install depends on the 3rd-party libraries you wish to use.  Some libraries only support the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends if your **Windows** is 64-bits or not. If it is, you should install Win64-AMD64, if not (32-bits) then x86.

Cheers.

Comment: He says in the title "64-bit windows 7" and in the question "I know I have Win64"

Comment: He could be referring to the processor in both cases. I prefer to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Yes I have a 64bit processor and OS!!